# Insert Multi para tags in a single cell in Excel sheet using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-17

I have an input coming as below:

```
<p style="font-family:Caveat;">This is Caveat</p><p style="font-family:Arial;">This is Arial text</p>
```

I want to insert both para tag element in a single cell as below using apache poi.
[image]

.I tried few example from net but I could find any appropriate solution for it.Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Excel cells don't contain text paragraphs. A cell only can contain single text runs having different text formatting. For that you will need [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) content in the cell.

Cell content also may contain line breaks. But line breaks only get effective if cell style is set to wrap text.

Using [XSSFRichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html) one can append different strings using different fonts using method [XSSFRichTextString.append](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html#append-java.lang.String-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont-).

The different fonts need to be created on workbook level. Same for the cell style.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class RichTextTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  
  XSSFCellStyle wrapTextCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
  wrapTextCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
  
  XSSFFont fontTNR = wb.createFont();
  fontTNR.setFontName("Times New Roman");
   
  XSSFFont fontArial = wb.createFont();
  fontArial.setFontName("Arial");
  
  XSSFRichTextString richString = new XSSFRichTextString();
  richString.append("This is Times New Roman", fontTNR);
  richString.append("\n");
  richString.append("This is Arial", fontArial);
  
  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
  XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
  XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);

  cell.setCellValue(richString);
  cell.setCellStyle(wrapTextCellStyle);
  
  sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 25*256);

  try ( FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("./workbook.xlsx"); ) {
   wb.write(fileOut);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: what if I have a text with <br> tag like <p style="font-family:Caveat;">This is <br>Caveat</p><p style="font-family:Arial;">This is Arial text</p>?? Do we need to append \n for that too?

Comment: @user2755407: Excel cell content has nothing to do with HTML at all. There are no paragraphs in Excel cell content. So only way to break line is line break `\n`.